# First-come-first-served policy for shared resource

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, scheduling

An exam question:

> A resource is shared between N threads such that access is on a first-come-first-served basis. Explain how you would implement a policy of first-come-first-served.

My answer would be along the lines of (Note: the course is Java-based):

> Use a semaphore (binary) to control access to the shared resource. Then create a feeder class/thread to access the semaphore. The feeder thread uses a FIFO queue to implement first-come-first-served. When the semaphore is free it allows the thread a the head of the queue to access the shared resource.

I have just jotted out on paper the above approach and it seems to work.

The question is worth 8 marks in a 20 mark question so I doubt using `new ReentrantLock(true)` would suffice for full marks.

What do you guys think?

Comment: The thread/s that cannot get the resource, (and so must wait), could enqueue 'this' on the queue and then wait on 'this'.  Threads releasing the resource can then pop the queue and notify() just that thread.  Not sure if a semaphore is the best answer here.  I would be tempted to make all the requesting threads and any releasing thread to acquire a lock on the queue and then sort their issues out inside that lock.

Comment: Regarding @MartinJames solution it is worth noting that sorting out issues inside the lock should not include the waiting on 'this'.

Comment: Regarding the original question: maybe it would be better to ask the instructor of the course to find what he expects? (telling him that you think that using new ReentrentLock(true)/Semaphore(1,true) is too easy ;-) Other than that your answer does not really provide the information how the waiting threads are blocked and unblocked, respectively, what you mean by "allows the thread ... to access". (and the feeder thread seems totally unnecessary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer really doesn't address the question.  This is not just about locking but is also about queuing the threads waiting for the resource.

- How do you queue the threads waiting for the resource?
- If there are threads waiting for the resource, how do you wake them up so they consume the resource in order.
- If there are threads waiting for the resource, how do you make sure they run in order and avoid the race condition around a new thread grabbing it.

A possible solution would be something like the following code:

```
  lockResource(resource);
  try {
     ... consume the resource
  } finally {
     unlockResource(resource);
  }
```

The `lockResource` would do something like:

1. Acquire the lock on the resource.
2. Retrieve the lock object associated with the resource that contains a `long accessNum` and a `long runningNum`.
3. increment the `accessNum` value and store the results for the thread.
4. check the `long runningNum` value to see if == to my `accessNum`.
5. If it is == mine, unlock resource and continue running.
6. If more than me in the queue, `wait()` on resource.

When `unlockResource(...)` is called, the thread should:

1. Lock resource.
2. Set `running++`
3. Call `notifyAll()`
4. Unlock resource

If a thread is waiting and gets awoken:

1. Check to see if the `accessNum == runningNum`.
2. If true then unlock resource and continue running
3. If not then go back to `wait()`